# Hotkey to switch to a specific window by title

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, utilities

I wish to create a hotkey to switch to a specific window (identified by its title) of an application - no matter if that application is currently active, or whether I am in fullscreen or split screen mode in another application.

I read through the Automator actions, and didn't see anything like "Change to window" or something like that. It can start/activate applications, but my target app has several top-level windows and I want exactly one of those.

Is this possible with onboard tools, or some small 3rd party utility?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke: thanks for bringing that up - it goes in the direction of what I need, but has no good answer as far as I can tell. They didn't find a way to switch to the correct workspace if the target window is in another one...

Comment: Ok, so the question than consists of two parts: 1) switch to the correct workspace 2) switch to the correct window. Can you edit your question to include that you can switch to the window using the method described in the other answers (check first if this works for you), but that you're looking for a solution to switching to the correct workspace?